# Pandas function calculation utilising previous row

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe with one Input column. I'd like to add another Out column that multiplies the input row by 0.5 + (previous row Out value + 1). I've tried shift but think I am missing something basic.

Input dataframe:

```
df
Out[11]: 
   Input  
0     10  
1     20  
2     30  
3     20  
4     30  
5      0  
6     10  
7     20
```

Output dataframe:

```
df
Out[11]: 
   Input  Out
0     10    5
1     20   16
2     30   32
3     20   43
4     30   59
5      0   60
6     10   66
7     20   77
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little trick to solve this problem:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'input':[10,20,30,20,30,0,10,20]})

print(df)
```

Input dataframe:

```
   input
0     10
1     20
2     30
3     20
4     30
5      0
6     10
7     20
```

What you are really doing in this situation is running a variant of a cumulative sum, which we can model as follows:

```
df['out'] = ((df['input']/2).cumsum()) + (df['input'].notnull()).cumsum().add(-1)
```

Output results:

```
   input   out
0     10   5.0
1     20  16.0
2     30  32.0
3     20  43.0
4     30  59.0
5      0  60.0
6     10  66.0
7     20  77.0
```

Comment: So I apply the function and then apply the cumsum() method. That really helps. Thanks all for the guidance.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.assign(Out=df.Input.cumsum() / 2 + np.arange(len(df)))

   Input   Out
0     10   5.0
1     20  16.0
2     30  32.0
3     20  43.0
4     30  59.0
5      0  60.0
6     10  66.0
7     20  77.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to be missing a value for the `0`th index, since there's no previous `'Out'` value there.

```
df['Input'] * 0.5 + (df['Out'].shift(1) + 1)
Out[24]: 
0     NaN
1    16.0
2    32.0
3    43.0
4    59.0
5    60.0
6    66.0
7    77.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you - could you explain how to do this if the Out column was not in the starting dataset please.